# How to select the color of node on data value and the Data value of tool as name?

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

1.How do I select a color for a node based on the mean values
2.Set the tooltip name format from the JSON file name. So on hover the name should be as "Hello", "Hello2", etc with their respective x and y values.

https://jsfiddle.net/npmarkunda/acd0sp05/

```
var jsonfile = [{
  "xvariable": "100",
  "valuevariable": "500",
  "name": "hello"
}, {
  "xvariable": "200",
  "valuevariable": "1500",
  "name": "hello2"
}, {
  "xvariable": "300",
  "valuevariable": "3500",
  "name": "hello5"
}];

var average = d3.mean(jsonfile.map(function(i) {
return i[1]
}));
console.log(average);

 var chart_scatterplot = c3.generate({
 point: {
 r: 7
 },
 data: {
    json: jsonfile,
    keys: {
        x: 'xvariable',
        value: ['valuevariable'],
        name: ['name'],
    },
    color: function(color, d) {
    console.log(d.name)
  if (d.value > average) {
    return "#F86A52"
  } else {
    return "#49B5A6"
  };
},
    type: 'scatter'
},
axis: {
x: {
  label: 'Interactions',
  tick: {
    fit: false
  },
  min: 1,
  max: 50000
},
y: {
  label: 'Days',
  min: 1,
  max: 9000
 }
 },
 legend: {
 show: false
 },
 tooltip: {
 format: {
 name: function (d) { return d.value; }
 }
 }
 });
```

Comment: can you fiddle the code so that we can play with it ?

Comment: this is the fiddle  - https://jsfiddle.net/npmarkunda/acd0sp05/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are calculating average is wrong.

Instead of calculating average like this:

```
var average = d3.mean(jsonfile.map(function(i) {
return i[1]//this is incorrect its not an array
}));
```

Do like this:

```
var average = d3.mean(jsonfile.map(function(i) {
  return i.valuevariable
}));
```

For tooltip add this config to the chart object

```
  tooltip: {
    contents: function(d, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color) {

      return jsonfile[d[0].index].name // formatted html as you want
    }
  },
```

Working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/k3pLjnos/3/)

Hops this helps!

Comment: Hey, Cyril! Thanks for the help. I integrated your code with my data. Can you please tell me why this graph node's are allover the place? https://jsfiddle.net/npmarkunda/yx3rjer1/3/ .For example the Company "Tester" has x = 3 and y = 14 but it shows at around x=275.

Comment: There's a new fiddle in the comment. - https://jsfiddle.net/npmarkunda/yx3rjer1/3/

Comment: Yeah it works really wierd!  I sorted and changed the scale and it worked here it is https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/yx3rjer1/5/

Comment: Anyway tooltip can be shown on click and not on hover? I need to to take some actions on the displayed tooltip.